# Sufficient condition for simple module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Every non-zero module homomorphism $f:M\rightarrow N$ is injective. Prove that $M$ is simple.

$f$ is not the zero map so $M$ is not $\{0\}$. I'm guessing I should let $N$ be a proper submodule of $M$ and pick a non-zero module homomorphism for which $N$ is the kernel. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the projection $M \twoheadrightarrow M/N$.

Comment: Ah, the beauty of simplicity. +1

Comment: just realised this implication is false unless they have the added assumption M is not {0}. If M={0}, then no non-zero homomorphism exist, so the hypothesis is vacuously satisfied, yet M would not be simple.

Comment: Yes. This is often forgotten.